# Как Rust считает количество вводимых символов из клавиатуры?

Tags: строки, rust

```
use std::io;
fn main() {
    println!("Hello enter your string and i'm count the number of charaster in if.");
    let mut s1 = String::new();
    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut s1)
        .expect("Some text...");

    let (s2, len) = calculate_length(s1);

    println!("The length of '{}' is {}.", s2, len);
}

fn calculate_length(s: String) -> (String, String) {
    let length = s.len() - 1; // len() returns the length of a String

    (s, length.to_string())
}
```

Доброго времени суток, уважаемые пользователи. Подскажите пожалуйста как в Rust происходит счет символов, которые пользователь вводит с клавиатуры? Что нужно изменить в коде чтобы результат выполнения функции calculate_length выводился корректно?

Comment: Что значит выводился корректно? Какой результат вы получаете, а какой ожидаете получить?

Comment: Ожидаемое поведение - вывод количества символов, которые содержатся в строке.
Выводятся совсем другие цифры.

Comment: Я ввёл "123" и мне вывело цифру 3. По моему нормально.

Comment: Этот код ведет себя предсказуемо только до поры, до времени.
Если попробовать ввести русские символы например, то результат уже не будет ожидаемым.

Comment: Вот в вопросе бы обозначили, что русские символы вводите, сразу было понятно в чём вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Для строк Rust использует кодировку `UTF-8`. В этой кодировке кириллица кодируется с помощью 2 байт. Соответственно длинна строки для русских букв будет в 2 раза больше.

Для подсчёта количества символов можно создать итератор по `Char` и подсчитать в нём количество элементов.

```
let length = s.trim().chars().count();
```

Comment: В общем случае это все равно может не дать желаемого результата, т.к. символ Unicode не всегда соответствует графическому или логическому символу человеческого языка: есть комбинирующие символы и другая экзотика.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ зависит от того, что считать "символом". Итераторы, возвращаемые методами `.chars()` и `.char_indices()`, позволяют сосчитать скалярные значения Unicode, из которых состоит строка. Но это не обязательно соответствует количеству графических или логических символов человеческого языка. В стандартной библиотеке нет полной поддержки стандартов Unicode, регламентирующих различные метрики текста, но можно воспользоваться библиотеками расширения из проекта unicode-rs:

- [unicode-width](https://crates.io/crates/unicode-width)
- [unicode-segmentation](https://crates.io/crates/unicode-segmentation)